# "python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory" when running tmux shell script?

Tags: linux, django, shell, terminal, tmux

I am trying to run a very simple tmux shell script called "split.sh" which splits the terminal windows.

split.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
~/build/tmux-1.5/tmux split-window -h
~/build/tmux-1.5/tmux split-window -v
~/build/tmux-1.5/tmux split-window -h
```

When I type the command "sh ~/build/tmux-1.5/split.sh", this shell script runs fine, splitting the terminal windows.

However, when I set an aliases,

```
alias sp='sh ~/build/tmux-1.5/split.sh'
```

and then run "sp", the terminal gives me a wierd error:

```
python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file
```

I believe this error with "manage.py" has something to do with Django.. but I have no idea why terminal is looking for manage.py. Why is the terminal giving me this error :(???

Thanks.

Comment: What does **type sp** say?

Comment: Presumably a new shell gets launched in each tmux window - what's in your .bashrc (or the equivalent for the shell you run)?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem. '*manage.py*' was in the directory but still was having this issue.

> python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

What I did was that mentioned complete path to the project where manage.py was located like this and ran the command successfully! it's because the file was located in a subdirectory. You need to either enter the appropriate subdirectory or add it to the filename as I did below

```
python C:\Users\myuser\python_projects\myproject\manage.py syncdb
```

Hopefully that will help you to resolve the issue.